# GitLab CI Trigger on Merge Request merged with available environment variables

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab Pipeline with following trigger rule

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
```

Currently this runs on every commit which is part of a merge request to master. I would like to only run the pipeline once the merge request is merged in to master. I can change the rule to:

```
only:
   - master
```

However, then I do not have access to the information I need from [`$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

How can I run a pipline after a merge request has been merged in to master while having access to `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID`?